# how reformat kegg reconstruct pathway in vim?

Tags: formatting, linux

I need to reformat the kegg reconstruct pathway output, I have something like this in file1:

```
00550 Peptidoglycan biosynthesis (2)

K01000

K02563

00511 Other glycan degradation (8)

K01190

K01191

K01192

K01201

K01227

K12309
```

I need something like:

```
00550 Peptidoglycan biosynthesis (2)   K01000   K02563
00511 Other glycan degradation (6)   K01190   K01191   K01192   K01201   K01227   K12309
```

How could I reformat this  like that in vim or linux

Comment: This can be done using a `:g` command. Something like this: `g/^0/,/^0\|\%$/-j`, which will mark each line starting with `0` and join until the next line starting with `0` (or end of line). However, it will miss the last line, so you need to add a final `:$-j` command to fix this. Posting here as comment, since question is on hold and answers can't be written

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt the original question asked "how can I do that on linux or python" that's why I closed it. IMO it still lacks some details to be really useful but you can post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a `:g` command.

Something like this:

```
g/^0/,/^0\|\%$/-j
```

This will mark each line (e.g. on which lines to act) starting with `0` and join until the next line starting with `0` (or end of line).

However, it will miss the last line, so you need to add a final

```
:$-j
```

command to fix this